# Responsive positioning of 6 boxes side by side

Tags: html, css

I am trying to position responsively 6 boxes side by side.
For lg I need 6 boxes next to eachother, then 4, then 3, then 2 for smaller devices. I need all boxes to be same width and fit always for the full 100% inside the container.

No clue why my below code does not work as I want. How to fix?

```css
.box2 {
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: #000;
    border: 2px solid #A10000;
    height: auto;
    width: 150px;
    font-size: 12px;
 }

.row {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}

.container {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container overview-sm">
        <div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
<a href="#" class="box2 dfs-1-sm" title="1"><h1>1</h1></a>
<a href="#" class="box2 dfs-2-sm" title="2"><h1>2</h1></a>
<a href="#" class="box2 dfs-3-sm" title="3"><h1>3</h1></a>
<a href="#" class="box2 dfs-4-sm" title="4"><h1>4</h1></a>
<a href="#" class="box2 dfs-5-sm" title="5"><h1>5</h1></a>
<a href="#" class="box2 dfs-6-sm" title="6"><h1>6</h1></a>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, a proper solution would take some effort. A few ideas would be to use media queries or flexbox. Maybe [this tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/filling-space-last-row-flexbox/) has a solution that works for you? Good luck :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of, a typo, where you missed the dot in the CSS rule, should be `.box2`

Second, those boxes can't be 100% wide at all times. Below I used `@media` query to set their size based on available screen width

```css
.box2 {
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  background-color: #FFF;
  color: #000;
  border: 2px solid #A10000;
  height: auto;
  width: calc((100% / 2) - 5px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.row {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .box2 {
    width: calc((100% / 3) - 5px);
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .box2 {
    width: calc((100% / 6) - 5px);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <a href="#" class="box2 dfs-1-sm" title="1"><h1>1</h1></a>
      <a href="#" class="box2 dfs-2-sm" title="2"><h1>2</h1></a>
      <a href="#" class="box2 dfs-3-sm" title="3"><h1>3</h1></a>
      <a href="#" class="box2 dfs-4-sm" title="4"><h1>4</h1></a>
      <a href="#" class="box2 dfs-5-sm" title="5"><h1>5</h1></a>
      <a href="#" class="box2 dfs-6-sm" title="6"><h1>6</h1></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure why you'd remove the width?

Comment: @agrm Most likely because I misunderstood the question. Will reread it

Comment: @LGSon - I need all boxes to be same width and fit always the full 100% inside the container.

Comment: @raulbaros Updated my answer. Is it now how you want?

Comment: @LGSon - very nice solution, perfect, exactly what I was after. THank you!

Comment: @LGSon - it works perfectly when I test it on my laptop and for different screen sizes, but on the actual physical devices (e.g. smartphone), it does not work. What can I do?

Comment: @raulbaros Have you setup your meta tags?: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: @LGSon - yes, I have Bootstrap3 and `<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">`

Comment: @raulbaros So what is it that does not work? .. Which resolution does the smart phone you test on have?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.
Is this the same that you want?

```html
<div class="container overview-sm">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
            <a href="#" class="box2 dfs-1-sm" title="1"><h1>1</h1></a>
            </div>

        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
            <a href="#" class="box2 dfs-1-sm" title="1"><h1>1</h1></a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
            <a href="#" class="box2 dfs-1-sm" title="1"><h1>1</h1></a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
            <a href="#" class="box2 dfs-1-sm" title="1"><h1>1</h1></a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
            <a href="#" class="box2 dfs-1-sm" title="1"><h1>1</h1></a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
            <a href="#" class="box2 dfs-1-sm" title="1"><h1>1</h1></a>
        </div>



        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```